# Cannot find declaration to go to in PHP Storm on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, phpstorm

Does someone have had this trouble on ubuntu - php storm doesn't see the declaration on classes somehow. On Windows system all works well.

Comment: Please try **File | Invalidate Caches...**

Comment: had the same problem on osx, and 'invalidating caches' worked for me. thanks, @LazyOne

Comment: I have this problem in phpStorm 9 (worked in 8) and for Javascript only. Tried WebStorm, same issue. Invalidating the cache didn't help me.

Comment: yes, **Invalidate Caches ...** is the solution on Windows to. PHPStorm Version 2020.3

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My problem was that my whole vendor folder had somehow gotten ignored.

To check and fix, navigate to "File > Settings > Project Settings > Directories" and make sure that "vendor" is not ***excluded***.

Sources:
http://fuelphp.com/forums/discussion/3943/how-to-setup-code-completion-in-phpstorm

Comment: There is no `Project Settings` in my phpstorm 2016.3.2

Comment: I believe that screen has been moved to just "Settings", with the previous rendition of "Settings" now being "Default Settings".

Comment: Now this is in `file>settings>directories`

Answer (score 5):

Please try to enable Laravel plugin:

`Settings (Preferences) | Other Settings | Laravel Plugin | Enable Plugin for this Project`

[image]

Or here:

`Languages & Frameworks | Php | Laravel| Enable Plugin for this Project`

[image]

As said on https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Laravel+Development+using+PhpStorm

Comment: not present this option in 2023

Answer (score 4):

- Nothing works for me like invalidate cache etc etc...
- Then I follow the following steps:
- First close the project from PhpStorm
- I was on mac, going to project by the finder.
- Enable hidden files and folders by pressing Shift + CMD + . (dot).  - Now i delete .editorconfig file.
- Delete .idea folder
- Now I open the project in Phpstorm.
- then everything was fine.

Comment: Deleting the `.idea` folder did the trick for me. Thanks for your comment, I lost some productive time to this crazy buggy behavior, and I'm a little-bit astonished by it.

Comment: @Julian thanks for your comments. You are the first man on the StackOverflow planet who find my suggested solution useful and give comments. :D

Answer (score 2):

Nothing worked for me, here is how i solved it :
Just restore Settings

```
File > Manage IDE Settings > Restore Default Settings
```

Uninstalling your IDE won't help, restoring settigns is the best way to solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

I had to delete the `.PhpStorm20*` folder in my home directory, starting with a completely new config. Maybe it's better this way after two years of dragging the same config along, across several versions of PhpStorm.

Comment: you could have just use the built-in 'file>invalidate caches + restart'

Answer (score 0):

I had this also and it was due to my URL.

I had:

```
templateUrl:'/features/UI/partials/labelledSelect.html'
```

And needed to make it:

```
templateUrl:'features/UI/partials/labelledSelect.html'
```

So I could control-click on it (in WebStorm actually though they seem to be extremely similar).

Answer (score 0):

I got "cannot find declaration..." in my file routes/web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

But after adding `use Illuminate\Routing\Route;`
it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my case PHP Storm didn't see declarations of standard php functions: `fopen()`, `fwrite` etc. These steps helped to fix this issue:

1. Download code of the official [phpstorm-stubs](https://github.com/JetBrains/phpstorm-stubs) repo to your PC as [zip archive](https://github.com/JetBrains/phpstorm-stubs/archive/master.zip).
2. Unpack it to some folder.
3. Open `Settings` > `Languages and frameworks` > `PHP`. Select `PHP Runtime` tab. At the bottom of the window you'll see `Default stubs path` option. Set it to the location where you have unpacked archive.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the “.php” file extension was associated with the text content type. Adding “*.php” to “file name patterns” under “Settings → File Types → PHP” has fixed it for me.